# Google Sheets Automation and Real Time Graphing

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

My knowledge of Google Sheets is somewhat limited. I have recently been keeping track of daily stock quotes (using the GoogleFinance function) and I was wondering how to utilize Google Sheets script editor to make a more automated and real time graph.

For example, I have columns with the stock price and volume that are updated every so often. I wanted to be able to take the values in these cells as they update and plot them in real time (as a line graph). I know Google script editor on Google Sheets has the ability to trigger at a certain time, so I would like the graphs to start populating at 9AM (when the markets begin to open) and stop populating at 4PM. I figure that updating the graph every 5 or 10 minutes would best enable me to capture the changes.

I wanted to do this to look at the relationships between various metrics (like the fluctuations in price and volume over time).  I do not know if Google Sheets is too limited to do something like this, but if you know of a way to do so, please do suggest it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need to use Apps Script here to achieve this Automation. I found here a [tutorial](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2469616/business-intelligence/business-intelligence-79661-how-to-create-an-automatically-updating-spreadsheet.html#slide1) that show how to create an automatically updating spreadsheet. But, sadly to say it did not mention here on how to create graph. But it will give you an idea on how to create automatic updating spreadsheets. You can also check this [Google Analytics Report Automation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic) and this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/how-should-i-automate-graph-generation-and-image-output-in-google-sheets) if it can help you in your case.